# Using LINQ when my where clause will contain a LIST

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List that I am trying to query using LINQ.  The T type has a property that is a  List < U >.  I am trying to query my List < T >'s List < U > property to pull only those objects who's List property items match the items in a seperate List < U > that I have built for filtering.  My code looks like this:

```
class T {
   List<U> Names;
}

class U {

}

//then I want to query a List of T by interrogating which T objects' Names property has the same items that I have a List < U > that I have created.

List<U> searchTermItems;
List<T> allObjects;

//Query allObjects and find out which objects' Name property items match the items in the searchTermItems list
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
var filtered = allObjects.Intersect(searchTermItems);
```

Because you are working with a collection of lists rather than a single list, in order to acheive the desired output you will need to use `Enumerable.Where` in conjunction with `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
var filtered = allObjects.Where(x => x.Names.Intersect(searchTermItems).Any());
```

Comment: The `allObjects` list won't have a property you can intersect like this - a `Where` should do it, though.  Something like `Where(t => t.Names.Intersect(searchTermItems).Count() > 0)`

Comment: compiler complaining that I am using a List<T> and that I need to be using IQueryable for Intersect.  What do I need to do here?  Do I need to cast the parent and the property lists to IQuerable<T>?